# Heightmap rendering with quads

Tags: opengl, geometry

I am trying to design a "low poly" terrain renderer, which takes in a heightmap and draws a tile/quad for each point (rather than a pixel/vertex).

I am having some trouble finding a way to "stitch" the quads together such that the centre of the quad is at the height specified in the heightmap.

What I have done so far is to simply set one vertex equal to the height of the "current" quad and the rest to the heights of the adjacent quads, for example something like:

Quad @ (x, y) with height from heightmap as "height(x,y)":

```
B   C
|---|  y
|   |  ^
|---|  |
A   D   --> x
```

With vertex heights:

```
heightA = height(x, y)
heightB = height(x, y + 1)
heightC = height(x + 1, y + 1)
heightD = height(x + 1, y)
```

Though this does join the quads together, it means the top right vertex (A) of the quad has the height specified rather of the centre.

**tl;dr**: Currently vertex of quad has a certain height, I would like the centroid of the quad to have this height instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
heightA = (height(x-1, y-1) + height(x-1, y) + height(x, y-1) + height(x, y))/4
heightB = (height(x-1, y) + height(x-1, y+1) + height(x, y) + height(x, y+1))/4
heightC = (height(x, y) + height(x, y+1) + height(x+1, y) + height(x+1, y+1))/4
heightD = (height(x, y-1) + height(x, y) + height(x+1, y-1) + height(x+1, y))/4
```

I.e. sample the height map at half-pixel locations with a bilinear interpolation. This has the same effect as box-blurring the height map, which is not such a good thing. You might use a different kernel, but essentially you cannot do much better.

The typical solution is to place the mesh vertices at the centers of the height-map texels, this way you preserve the height-map resolution without any spacial shifts.

Comment: To clarify your last point; do you mean (for example) creating a quad from four triangles such that they all have a common vertex (in the centre of the quad) that can be set to the height?

Comment: Nope, just two triangles per quad. Like you do today but shift it by half-pixel in the XY plane.